# Very Simple jQuery click through gallery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I've been looking through all the galleries and most are too complicated for my use - I need a simple way to stack nine images in a div and onClick rotate through and then cycle back to the top.  Are there any good tutorials or a simple jQuery script to use for this?

Answer (score 3):

I've used this http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ quite a bit.

It's JQuery Cycle and the author provides a lot of great tutorials.

Hope this helps you out!